# How does the Linux kernel know which driver functions to call?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, wifi

I am looking at the 802.11 Realtek driver code from [https://github.com/o11s/open80211s/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180](http://rtl8180%20driver) and can’t figure out how either the kernel knows which driver functions to call.

For example, how does it know if it needs to call write_grf5101 or rtl8225_write in order to transmit a datagram?

From rtl8225.c:

```
static void rtl8225_write(struct ieee80211_hw *dev, u8 addr, u16 data)
{
...
}
```

From grf5101.c:

```
static void write_grf5101(struct ieee80211_hw *dev, u8 addr, u32 data)
{
...
}
```

Comment: post the appropriate code spinets here. A question should be answerable without checking external resources.

Comment: I have added the code snippets for the transmit functions I was referring to.

Comment: According to the code, the driver selects proper functions set during the [probing](https://github.com/o11s/open80211s/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180/dev.c#L1042) by checking some value read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two functions are not called by the kernel itself. They are *static* and reside in corresponding files (probably, chip-specific files). Also, it seems like they are not used as *callbacks* in either place.

Instead, you may see that, for example, `write_grf5101()` is [used](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/grf5101.c#L118) by `grf5101_rf_init()` function in `./drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/grf5101.c` file, and that function *is* [set as a callback](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/grf5101.c#L185) in `rtl818x_rf_ops` structure which in turn, as you might understand, is some sort of like more generic entity within the driver. For instance, that `grf5101_rf_ops` variable (which is of type `struct rtl818x_rf_ops`) is [set as a callback table](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/dev.c#L1892) by `rtl8180_probe()` function in `./drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/dev.c`. And, finally, the latter `rtl8180_probe()` is [set as a callback](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl818x/rtl8180/dev.c#L1990) in `rtl8180_driver` variable of type `struct pci_driver` which, as you might see, is some sort of like an interface maintained by the kernel itself (all PCI devices register themselves with `struct pci_driver`). The line `module_pci_driver(rtl8180_driver);` below performs such registration in this particular case.

So, the point is that "the kernel" doesn't know (and probably shouldn't) about such tiny static helper routines. Instead, the kernel needs a PCI device description structure which in turn will be used all way round to interface a particular device. A typical driver, however, *may have* (and often has) its *internal* callback structures - often chip-specific (in the case when the driver is designed to serve multiple chips in some sort of like device family) - which in turn will point to chip-specific functions located in the corresponded `.c` files. That internal functions may use such helpers (like `rtl8225_write()` or `write_grf5101()`), and there is nothing to do with *kernel* in that case. They are just some tiny chip-specific helpers.